# Why does csv.reader fail when the file size is larger than 40K bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file, reader

I have the following code:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as csvfile:
    csvDictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvDictReader:
        print(row)
```

Whenever the file size is less than 40k bytes, the program works great.
When the file size crosses 40k, I get this error while trying to read the file:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 7206: invalid start byte
```

The actual file content doesn't seem to be a problem, only the size of the file itself (40k bytes is really tiny).

When file size is greater than 40K bytes, the error always happens on the line that contains the 32K-th byte.

I have a feeling that python fails to read the file that is more than 40K bytes without an exception, and just truncates it around the 32K-th byte, in the middle. Is that correct? Where is this limit defined?

Comment: It _is_ the file content, not the file size. You have a non-Unicode byte in position 7206.

Comment: No, Python has no such limit.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? Do you expect to have any non-Ascii characters in the file? Do you know how its encoded? And most obviously, have you cracked open an editor and checked what's at character position 7206? You could `print(open(filename, 'rb').read(7240)[7190:])` to take a peek at the characters in that area.

Comment: @tdelaney: The fact that it's trying to decode at all indicates it's Python 3; Python 2's `open` doesn't decode, and Python 2's `csv` module doesn't handle the `unicode` type even if it did (`from io import open` would get Py3-style `open` in Py2, but it wouldn't be compatible with `csv`, which only handles `str` type in Py2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid UTF-8 data in your file. This has nothing to do with the `csv` module, nor the size of the file; your larger file has invalid data in it, your smaller file does not. Simply doing:

```
 with open(filename) as f:
     f.read()
```

should trigger the same error, and it's purely a matter of encountering an invalid UTF-8 byte, which indicates your file either wasn't UTF-8 to start with, or has been corrupted in some way.

If your file is actually a different encoding (e.g. `latin-1`, `cp1252`, etc.; the `file` command line utility might help with identification, but for many ASCII superset encodings, you just have to *know*), pass that as the `encoding` argument to `open` to use instead of the locale default (`utf-8` in this case), so you can decode the bytes properly, e.g.:

```
    # Also add newline='' to defer newline processing to csv module, where it's part
    # of the CSV dialect
    with open(filename, encoding='latin-1', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvDictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in csvDictReader:
            print(row)
```

Comment: For the record, in either `latin-1` or `cp1252`, `\xa0` is the encoding of the non-breaking space (equivalent to HTML escape `&nbsp;`). You wouldn't see it in a regular text editor or spreadsheet viewer (not in any way distinguishable from a plain space), but a hex editor should make it plain as day.

Comment: The f.read() trick was helpful, There was a hidden character on the 3rd-to-last line, which was the line that had the 40K-th byte (so when I removed that line and following lines I thought that by reducing to under 40k I was fixing the problem)

Answer (score 0):

the file size is not the real problem
see the exception:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 7206: invalid start byte

you should handle the encoding problem at first

```
with open(filename, 'rt', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
```

which will ignore the encoding errors

Comment: Assuming the csv is utf-8 encoded. That may be the default for read but it doesn't mean its correct for the file.

Comment: `errors="ignore"` is only the correct solution when you have a file that is *known* to be UTF-8, but has been corrupted in some way. For everything else, it means "I don't care about correctness, and will happily lose data all over the place." Figure out the correct encoding and use that, don't just say "UTF-8 is the only possible encoding, so it *must* be ignorable corruption." Odds are, it's perfectly valid `cp1252`, produced by some Windows program that was told to use the locale encoding rather than UTF-16 (common portable encoding for Windows) or UTF-8 (portable encoding everywhere else).